# Am I Using Deepcopy wrong?

Tags: python, copy

I have a class that has a list as one of its attributes:

```
class Hello(object):
    stuff
    self.List = [True, False, True False]
```

I want to pass a copy of that list into a tuple so I can change the list while referring back to previous copies of the list. I do the following:

```
def getStartState(self):
    copiedList = copy.deepcopy(self.cornerList)
    fullState = (self.startingPosition[0], self.startingPosition[1], tuple(copiedList))
    return fullState
```

I am getting an error telling me that copy is not a global variable. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have `import copy` anywhere?

Comment: Also, for a tuple of True/False values, copy is unnecessary. Just do `tuple(self.List)`. It will create a copy.

Comment: or use slicing :)  self.list[:]  should return a copy ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I dislike using that syntax for shallow copying - it's much less clear than the obvious ``list(some_list)``.

Comment: meh I am on the opposite side ... I know both are copies ... but slicing comes naturally to me and requires (marginally) less typing .. . I think its just a personal preference type thing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few issues here.

First off, your error is probably because you are not importing the `copy` module. That is an easy fix. Just at `import copy` at the top of your file.

The second issue is that there's no need to `deepcopy` a list of immutable objects like `bool`s. Since the list's members can't be changed in place, any of `copy.copy(List)`, `list(List)` or `List[:]` will work just fine. Deep copying is only necessary if there are nested mutable structures.

Finally, there's no need to copy a list just to make a tuple out of the copy. Tuple's are immutable and don't modify their source sequence, so you can make your `getStartState` method simpler:

```
def getStartState(self):
    return (self.startingPosition[0], self.startingPosition[1],
            tuple(self.cornerList))
```